# KILE replace phrase in all project files

Tags: kile

I know it is not directly a LaTeX question, but it is regarding the TeX-editor KILE:

There is a "Find in Project" option but I don't find any "Replace in Project" option. Is there any? What is the easiest way to replace all "ABC" strings by "abc" in all project files?

Comment: Are you on Windows? If not, I recommend `sed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cfr's suggestion (non-Windows environment):

Close Kile. Open a terminal. Enter:

```
$ cd path/to/project/
$ sed -i~ 's/foo/bar/g' *.tex
```

- `foo` is the phrase to be replaced, and `bar` is the replacement phrase.
- The `-i~` option is to generate a `.tex~` backup file for each modified `.tex` file.